# Laravel Validation login

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication

This time I'm learning validation. I can't do this for my login form... 
My code looks like this right now, It works only when I have errors, but this code don't want to login my user. What should be in my code to work and why It doesn't work now? I don't know too how this validate know which email and password should compare to login and from which table? Should I add this info somewhere?

```
public function login(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'           => 'required|max:255|email',
        'password'           => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

        return redirect()->intended('/panel');

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider adding the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` to your Controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers; // <- add this line

    // ...
}
```

Then you can throw your `login` method and everything will work. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

But if you want to build your own Authentication system (**I don't recommend**), you have to dig more. You could have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users). Then update your controller like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'           => 'required|max:255|email',
        'password'           => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Success
        return redirect()->intended('/panel');
    } else {
        // Go back on error (or do what you want)
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```